# AngularJS Expression not evaluated over Windows Homegroup

Tags: angularjs, expression

I am working through an AngularJS code sample from the Pluralsight course, AngularJS for .NET Developers.  I've created a simple website on a Windows 8.1 machine, named SIMMA, on a Homegroup with a simple HTML page, hello.html, running on port 81:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
    Hello {{1 + 1}} the world!
</body>
```

The expression {{1 + 1}} is evaluated locally with the URL, http://localhost:81/hello.html.  However, it does not evaluate from other machines using the URL, http://simba:81/hello.html.  The string, "Hello {{1 + 1}} the world!", is displayed and the expression is not evaluated.  What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Are you seeing any error in log? Angular loaded fine?

Comment: Try loading angular with `src="//ajax.googleap..."` instead of specifying the protocol

Comment: Some additional information; I tried the load Angular both ways with the same behavior.  Also I ran it from another machine using Chrome and it worked.  It seems the problem is with IE11, our default brower everywhere.  I've seen some posts on erratic behavior with IE11.  I'll look at it and post back.  The idea behind using Javascript libraries like jQuery and Angular is to avoid coding for specific browsers.  It seems our friends in Redmond need to do somethin'.